# count the value "x" in vba

Tags: vba, excel

i need a solution for the following situation:
I have an Exel file with 4 sheets.
the structure of all sheets are the same, only the content is different.

Explanation:

- The user have to set a "x" in the area D9:I9 (this "x" have to be count in all sheets. but there is an special situation:
- The user can set an "y" in the area K9:P9

In that case should only count all "x" of this sheet after the "y" area

Example:

Sheet 1: D9:I9 ("x") = 6 "x"
[image]

Sheet 2: D9:I9 ("x") = 6 "x"
[image]

Sheet 3: D9:I9 ("x") = 6 "x" | M9 ("y")
[image]

And in sheet 3 is the special situation.
The user has set 6 "x", but an "y" too.

This means, that the "x" which are set before and in the same area like the "y" should not be counted.

i have the following vba code, whichs count me all "x" but not wit this "special situation" (i don't know how)

```
Function breaking_count()

Const Area_x As String = "$D$9:$I$9"
Const Area_y As String = "$K$9:$P$9"

Dim Nr As Integer, Count_x As Integer


For Nr = 4 To 1 Step -1

    With Worksheets(CStr(Nr))

        If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(Area_y), "*y*") > 0 Then Exit For
        Count_x = Count_x + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(Area_x), "*x*")

    End With

Next
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code will display the **message box** for each sheet with count of `x`.

```
Sub breaking_count()
    Const Area_x As String = "$D$9:$I$9"
    Const Area_y As String = "$K$9:$P$9"
    Dim Nr As Integer, Count_x As Integer, Col_Ind
    Dim temp_Area As Range

    For Nr = 4 To 1 Step -1
        'With Worksheets(CStr(Nr))
        With Worksheets(Nr)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(Area_y), "*y*") > 0 Then
                'find the index of "y" in Area_y
                Col_Ind = WorksheetFunction.Match("y", .Range(Area_y))
                'Reset the range Area_y in temp_Area using offset
                Set temp_Area = .Range(.Cells(9, 4).Offset(0, Col_Ind), .Cells(9, 9))
                Count_x = Count_x + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(temp_Area, "*x*")
            Else
                Count_x = Count_x + WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(Area_x), "*x*")
            End If
            MsgBox Worksheets(Nr).Name & " : " & Count_x
            Count_x = 0
        End With

    Next
End Sub
```

Let me know if anything is not clear.